# How to get Blocks and Child Blocks for a Page in Notion?

Tags: python, notion-api, notion

I have a page `https://www.notion.so/Wiki-Page-For-a-Business-Case-8ec70cd1894711a862acc61a47fdb74d`.

I would like to access this page through Python an extract its blocks. I have added successfully the Connection, received the API Key but i cannot access a site by its url or anything else through the Notion API.

Has someone an idea how this could be achieved or i have just overseen a API for this purpose.

I have tried also to use the search api:

```
url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/search"
token = 'secret_S5PPXrnCcJ3mA1234gYSGHzvt123dYQE2j4112bePAMD'

search_params = {"filter": {"value": "page", "property": "object", "content": "Wiki Page for a Business Case"}}
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28",
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=search_params, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

but this gives me

```
{"object":"error","status":400,"code":"validation_error","message":"body failed validation: body.filter.content should be not present, instead was `\"Wiki Page for a Business Case\"`."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this API but the `filter` parameter seems to accept only two keys, `"value"` and `"property"`, if I read the [`search`](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-search) documentation.

Maybe you can replace:

```
search_params = {"filter": {"value": "page", "property": "object",
                            "content": "Wiki Page for a Business Case"}}
```

With:

```
search_params = {"filter": {"value": "page", "property": "object"},
                 "query": "Wiki Page for a Business Case"}
```